# ¿Comó convertir un cadena string a un List object?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo lo siguiente

```
[com.example.buscart.app.models.State@63fe9fa, 
com.example.buscart.app.models.State@3dcfbab, 
com.example.buscart.app.models.State@b077208]
```

y necesito convertirlo a una lista tipo `List<State>`

Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo.

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que intentaste, que es el objeto State? lo podrías agregar por favor.Agrega un ejemplo de que se agregaría en el List

Comment: ¿El método toString() esta definido en la clase State?, ¿de donde viene el array?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres convertir un arreglo a una lista, puedes simplemente utilizar el método [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

```
String[] strings = {"Hola", "mundo", "ja"};

List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(strings);
System.out.println(strs);
```

Dado que una lista (`List<E>`) es una interfaz que es implementada por muchas otras clases de *Collections framework*, la puedes crear también de diferentes maneras, e. g. con un ArrayList

```
String[] strings = {"Hola", "mundo", "ja"};

List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>(strings.length);
for (String str : strings)
    strs.add(str);
```